# Custom control names (not ID) in ASP.NET to use with JQ.serialize

Tags: asp.net, ajax, namevaluecollection

I am developing a website using mainly AJAX for saving and retrieving data in order to avoid postbacks (or at least full postbacks).
I "prepare" the page in codebehind, and on client I use JQ and Javascript.
When I want to save data I serialize the elements in a container (using JQ) and then AJAX post to send data to the WebMethod.
This is working well but I have to deal with long name elements ("ctl00$MainContent$grdEmployees$ctl03$ddlRole").
Sometimes is difficult to retrive data from the NameValueColletion as the same WebMethod can be called from different pages, so the "name" of the element is not the same as the control may be nested in other container.

Is there a way to set custom names for ASP.NET controls to avoid this issue?
Or other way to achieve this behavior?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ClientIDMode="Static" which is found in .NET 4.5.

When a page is render the ids all change as you have noted.  However, you set the ClientIDMode to static it will render with the ID that you have put for the control itself.  That way you can work with the ID of the control instead of the generated id.  If you would like to know more here is a like to the MSDNA about ClientIDMode

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I set ClientIDMode to Static but it only affects control IDs and not control Names.
JQ.serialize uses control Names, it works the same way when you post a form, key-value pair is generated. You access values by its key, that is the Name of the control and not the ID.